# @aws-sdk/client-s3 producing error on image upload

Tags: amazon-s3

this is the code

```
const client = new S3({
    region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION,
    credentials: {
        ccessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY
    }
})

const upload = async (name, file, bucket=process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET) => {

    const uploader = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: name,
        Body: Buffer.from(file.data)
    }

    const upload = await client.putObject(uploader, (err, data) => {
        console.log('callback')
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data)
    })

    return {
        etag: upload.ETag.replace(/\"/g,""),
        location: upload.Location,
        key: Key,
        bucket: bucket
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
400: UnknownError
    at throwDefaultError (/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-    handler.js:8:22)
    at deserializeAws_restXmlPutObjectCommandError (/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:5782:43)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
    at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/middleware.js:14:20
    at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
    at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-flexible-checksums/dist-cjs/flexibleChecksumsMiddleware.js:58:20
    at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26 {
        '$fault': 'client',
        '$metadata': {
        httpStatusCode: 400,
        requestId: '6ACVW778TJGP01YP',
        extendedRequestId:    'qv518QMX7msriUZgvRtEvysSdhAMKb2xUWUlEc8aOrkZSBB/Z7kQ2AAXLZU6KsUF4NOzLX01Fs4=',
        cfId: undefined,
        attempts: 1,
        totalRetryDelay: 0
    }
}
```

trying to upload a image to s3. the error it's generating is horrible, i tried to find the solution everywhere, nothing seems working. The generated error saying its UnknownError. how i am suppose to find the problem and fix it where aws is saying it's a unknown error :D.